# Postman AssertionError when testing using a defined function

Tags: postman

I have a Postman request getting a json response like so:

```
{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "Type": "Melee",
            "Captain": "Falcon",
            "Falco": "Lombardi",
            "Fox": "McCloud",
            "Princess": "Peach",
            "Kirby": null
        },
        {
            "Type": "Brawl",
            "Captain": "Toad",
            "Falco": "The bird",
            "Fox": "Blip",
            "Princess": "Daisy",
            "Kirby": null
        },
        {
            "Type": "64",
            "Captain": "America",
            "Falco": "Dair",
            "Fox": "Shine",
            "Princess": "Float",
            "Kirby": null
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to test all the values returned. The problem is that it won't always be in this order; for example, in the future, '64' might be sent first then 'Brawl' then 'Melee' or something along those lines. So I'm trying to make a loop that checks which type it is, then tests accordingly:

```
for(var i in jsonResponse.Rules)
{
    if(jsonResponse.Rules[i] == "Melee")
        {
            pm.test("Melee Captain is Falcon", testFunction(jsonResponse.Rules[i].Captain, "Falcon");
            pm.test("Melee Falco is Lombardi", testFunction(jsonResponse.Rules[i].Falco, "Lombardi");
            //repeat for fox, princess and kirby
        }
    if(jsonResponse.Rules[i] == "Brawl")
        {
            pm.test("Brawl Captain is Toad", testFunction(jsonResponse.Rules[i].Captain, "Toad");
            //repeat for the rest
        }
    if(jsonResponse.Rules[i] == "64")
        {
             pm.test("64 Captain is America", testFunction(jsonResponse.Rules[i].Captain, "America");                
             //repeat for the rest
        }
}
```

And here is the testFunction method:

```
function testFunction(value, shouldEqualThis)
{
    pm.expect(value).to.eql(shouldEqualThis);
}
```

This will work when the test passes, but if the test fails I get the following error:

```
There was an error in evaluating the test script:  
AssertionError: expected 'FalconSpelledWrong' to deeply equal 'Falcon'
```

This is the case for anytime I do 'pm.test' that calls 'testFunction' with values that don't match.

I just want the test to fail rather than break the script.

**Core Problem: I don't understand what the difference is between this:** (working)

```
pm.test("Melee Captain is Falcon", function() {
    pm.expect(jsonResponseData.Rules[0].Captain).to.eql("FalconSpelledWrong");
})
```

and this: (not working)

```
pm.test("Falcon equals FalconSpelledWrong", stringCompare("Falcon", "FalconSpelledWrong"));

function stringCompare(value, shouldEqualThis)
{
    pm.expect(value).to.eql(shouldEqualThis);
}
```

The first one will just fail the test and move on. The second will throw an AssertionError.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is

With first you are passing a callback function (throws AssertionFailure)
while with second you are explicitly calling the function (throws AssertionError)